# Swift core data: keypath not found in entity error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an error with fetching core data in swift.
My code is like this

```
var mealResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Food>!

private func setUpMealResultController() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Food> = Food.fetchRequest()
    let userPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "user == %@", User.user!)
    let sortPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "sort == %@", "meal")
    let sortDescripter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [userPredicate, sortPredicate])
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescripter]
    
    mealResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: dataController.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    
    mealResultController.delegate = self
    do {
        try mealResultController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Fetch cannot be performed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

and core data is like this

[coredata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjAyC.png)

When I perform fetch in try mealResultController.performFetch(), error occurs like this.

> 2021-08-18 15:03:51.412345+0900 MealPlanner209[9647:205175] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x6000037d0d20> , keypath name not found in entity Food with userInfo of (null)
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x6000037d0d20> , keypath name not found in entity Food with userInfo of (null)
> 2021-08-18 15:03:51.424753+0900 MealPlanner209[9647:205175] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath name not found in entity Food'

Comment: You don’t have an attribute `name` in `Food`, that is what the error message says and that is what your image of your entities clearly shows.

Comment: How foolish I am... I just focused on NSPredicate.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says that your `Food` object doesn't have `name`. According to your image you don't have such property if your `Food` object

I suggest you use key paths instead of string variables, this will allow you to get errors at build time rather than crashes at runtime:

```
let key = NSExpression(forKeyPath: \Food.name).keyPath
let sortDescripter = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: false)
```